# trying to append an html list using php code?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have this php script inside of an html list element that allows the user to edit the html elemnt directly from the webpage if the variable ?pw = "password". I want the user to also have the ability to add list items for them to edit, Is there a way to append another list item in html using php? I know you can just use .append() in javascript... this is the php script I am talking about:

```
 <li>
    <?php
        if ($_POST['pw']!="") {
            $pw=($_POST['pw']);
        } else {
            $pw=($_GET['pw']);
        }
        $newcontent2=($_POST['newcontent2']);
        $filelocation2 = "content/event2-1.txt";
        if (!file_exists($filelocation2)) {
            echo "Couldn't find datafile, please contact the administrator. huberwb@g.cofc.edu";
        } else {
            $newfile2 = fopen($filelocation2,"r");
            $content2 = fread($newfile2, filesize($filelocation2));
            fclose($newfile2);
        }
        $content2 = stripslashes($content2);
        $content = htmlentities($content2,ENT_HTML5);
        /*set password */   
        $pass = "password";
        if (!$pw || $pw != $pass){
            $content2 = nl2br($content2);
            echo $content2;
        } else {
            if($newcontent2){
                $newcontent2 = stripslashes($newcontent2);
                $newfile2 = fopen($filelocation2,"w");
                fwrite($newfile2, $newcontent2);
                fclose($newfile2);
                echo "Text has been edited.";
                echo "<form><input type= 'submit' value='see changes' class='button'/></form>";
            } else {
                echo "<form method='post'> <textarea name ='newcontent2' style= 'width:100px; height:20px; border: 3px solid # ccc; font-family: sans-serif; font-size:small;' cols ='auto' rows='auto' wrap='virtual'>";
                echo $content2;
                echo "</textarea>
                <input type='hidden' name='pw' value= '".$pass."' />
                <br /><input type='submit' value='edit' class='button' />
                </form>";
            }
        }
    ?>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is rendered server side as the page loads.

A change by the user i.e. a new item in the list can only be added by PHP with a new request. This could be done in a number of ways i.e. a full page refresh where a form sends the request and the page reloads with the new list entry. Or you could send the form off with JavaScript/jQuery to PHP and then get some return html to `append()` to the list.

Hope that helps.